# Deploying Next JS using Docker and Aws Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, next.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to deploy next js (12.3.1) using AWS Elastic Beanstalk + Docker.

Deployment fails with the error :

```
Step 31/36 : COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY failed: stat app/.next/standalone: file does not exist
```

Here is my dockerfile : https://gist.github.com/younes-alouani/6401184545f41ed55c2a2603dea87eb7

To automatically copy tracing files, i added this to my next js config file :

```
module.exports = { output: 'standalone', }
```